# an indeterminate progressbar in new window in swt

Tags: java, progress-bar, swt, windowbuilder

I am designing interface of java application using window builder. What I need to do is..
Click on a button does two things 1. do some background task 
2. while this is in progress, display an indeterminate progressbar n new window.
I know I need multithreading to accomplish this.

I tried taking the help of some tutorials but could not implement this.

Can anyone help?

code:
Function from where I want to open the progress bar window

```
public void mouseDown(MouseEvent e) {
pbar p=new pbar();
p.caller();
dowork();
```

p.closeprogress();

```
}
```

Progressbar class

```
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;


public class pbar {

protected Shell shell;

public void pcaller() {
    try {
    //System.err.println("Error: " + bod);


//System.err.println("Error: " + lines);
        pbar window = new pbar();
        window.open();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Open the window.
 */
public void open() {
    Display display = Display.getDefault();
    createContents();
    shell.open();
    shell.layout();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Create contents of the window.
 */
protected void createContents() {
    shell = new Shell();
    shell.setSize(315, 131);
    shell.setText("Updating!!! Please Wait");

    ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar(shell, SWT.INDETERMINATE);
    progressBar.setBounds(47, 34, 195, 17);
//  ProgressBar pb2 = new ProgressBar(shell, SWT.HORIZONTAL | 

SWT.INDETERMINATE);
   // pb2.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_HORIZONTAL));
}

public void close()
{
    shell.close();
}
}
```

I want when I call p.caller(), progress bar will appear. Then, control should come to original program and execute dowork() method. when i am done with this method, it will call p.progress.close().
I Don't know why isn't understanding this simple program, forget about answering.

Answer (score 4):

Is use of JFace acceptable?
If so you can use ProgressMonitorDialog class.

```
ProgressMonitorDialog dialog = new ProgressMonitorDialog(parent.getShell());
dialog.run(true, true, new SomeTask());

...

class SomeTask implements IRunnableWithProgress {

    @Override
    public void run(IProgressMonitor monitor) throws InvocationTargetException,
            InterruptedException {
        monitor.beginTask("Doing some task", IProgressMonitor.UNKNOWN);
        for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            if (!monitor.isCanceled())
                Thread.sleep(10);
        }

        monitor.done();
    }
}
```

You can find complete [example of usage](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/JFacesProgressMonitorDialog.htm) here.

Comment: I don't want to set the time. When new dialog bx opens, displaying the progress bar, I want it to be indeterminate ie going through a cycle and then I want the control to go back to the calling program and do some task, after this task is over, I will close the progress bar window.

Comment: There is no need to set time.
Just call beginTask.run with IProgressMonitor.UNKNOWN parameter before actual work of task is started. And you will get progress monitor with looping animation. That animation will stop right after monitor.done is invoked from background task code.

Comment: As i understood it, the first two lines are to be written in calling program. there it is showing error in parent.getShell() .

Comment: @VIPULGOYAL as I can see, you can not provide proper shell from mouseDown handler. So please try to pass Display.getActiveShell() to ProgressMonitorDialog's constructor instead of parent.getShell(). That shall work. But it would be better to find related shell to the mouse event that occurs.

Comment: OK, a progress dialog opens, but the control remains in it until all those iterations are done. Only after that, any statement written after dialog.run(true, true, new SomeTask()); executes. Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

Try using.....

```
JProgressBar p = new JProgressBar();
p.setStringPainted();
```

Now where the value needs to be set.

```
 p.setValue(val);
```

To display a message when done.

```
p.setString("done");
```

Comment: i don't want a value to be set. I dont know how much time my other task will take, so progress bar should be an indeterminate one.

Comment: using setValue() i wrote a program where i used progress bar and it shows the value according to the progress, if its taking time, the progress value remains constant till the time taking work is not done... and then progress accordingly,, Now if you dont want the setValue(), dont use it..as simple as that..

Comment: The method setStringPainted() is undefined for ProgressBar.

Comment: JProgressBar does have setStringPainted(boolean b) method...try it out..i have edited the code for your help

Comment: no progress bar is shown up on screen by using topmost two lines.